# Cambiar el estilo de TABLAS mysql html

Tags: mysql, html5

estoy haciendo un CRUD y me gustaria modificar la forma en la que se ven las tablas.

Actualmente el codigo es:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "bdnutriologo")or
die( "Problemas con la conexión" );

$registros = mysqli_query( $conexion, "select *
                    from tipo_menu")or
die( "Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error( $conexion ) );

while ( $reg = mysqli_fetch_array( $registros ) )


{
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>ID Menu:</th><td>" . $reg[ 'id_menu' ] . "</td></tr><br>";
echo "<tr><th>Comidas Diarias:</th><td>" . $reg[ 'cantidad_comidas' ] . " 
</td></tr><br>";
echo "<tr><th>Nombre:</th><td>" . $reg[ 'nombre' ] . "</td></tr><br>";
echo "<tr><th>Descripcion:</th><td>" . $reg[ 'descripcion' ] . "</td></tr> 
<br>";


} 

mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Y se ve asi:

[image: La tabla se ve asi (me separa los registros por id en distintas tablas]
quisiera que se vea asi:Que se vea como una lista Y que muestre los registros en una sola tabla

[image: Que se vea como una lista Y que muestre los registros en una sola tabla]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que sacar tu table tag de el loop asi:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "bdnutriologo")or
die( "Problemas con la conexión" );

$registros = mysqli_query( $conexion, "select *
                from tipo_menu")or
die( "Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error( $conexion ) );
echo "<table><thead><tr><th>ID Menu:</th><th>Comidas Diarias:</th>";
echo "<th>Nombre:</th><th>Descripcion:</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
while ( $reg = mysqli_fetch_array( $registros ) )
{    
    echo "<tr><td>" . $reg[ 'id_menu' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $reg[ 'cantidad_comidas' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $reg[ 'nombre' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $reg[ 'descripcion' ] . "</td></tr>     
} 
echo "</tbody></table>";
mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Comment: Hola, no me ha funcionado ahora solo aparece una tabla.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  La idea es que pongas dentro del loop solo lo que se repite.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me funciono y aprendi algo nuevo. Gracias!